# Terms in a geometric sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the maximum number of terms in a strictly increasing geometric sequence, where each term is an integer between $100$ and $1000$ (inclusive). I tried making many cases but it didn't help.

Comment: $a_0=2^7=128$ and $r=\dfrac32=1.5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to optimize number of terms in sequence you desire by keeping the common ratio quite small, as well as keep all of the terms an integer between 100 and 1000, you need a first term which is quite small, and which will result in only integer values between 100 and 1000. I can just think of r=3/2 and starting term to be 128, as $2^7 = 128$, meaning it will only result in integer values between 100 and 1000 (As it has 7 twos in its prime factorisation).

So I think 128, 192, 288, 432, 648, 972 is the longest geometric sequence; 6 terms

In fact, since 2 is the smallest integer factor besides one, the starting term $2^7$ will yield most terms for the common ratio (Which again has 3/2, smallest integer factors for denominator and numerator respectively (Because we wish to optimise the number of terms in the sequence and keep the denominator a factor capable of resulting in only integer values between 100 and 1000)). So I have more assurance now that this is the correct answer...

Answer (score 2):

Proof there is no sequence of length $7$:

Let $\frac{p}{q}$ be the ratio with $(p,q)=1$ and $a_0=b$ . Then $a_6=\frac{bp^6}{q^6}$ Hence $q^6|b$.

Since the only numbers in $[100,1000]$ which are divisible by a sixth power are $2^7,2^8,2^9$ We must have that $b$ is equal to one of these. And therefore $q$ must be a power of $2$. However if $q=2^k$ with $k\geq 2 $ then $(2^{k})^6=2^{6k}$ will not divide $b$. So if we want for the sequence to have more than six terms we must have $q=2$.

From here $p\geq 3$ and therefore $a_6\geq 2^7\frac{3^6}{2^6}=2\cdot3^6>1000$.

Therefore no sucession of length $7$ exists and $6$ is indeed the max.

Comment: Nice. Was in the process of editing my answer with the almost same proof I finally found; looks like you posted it before me.